# $.when.done callback isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, .when

The following code has a bad syntax error. Probably because I'm using 'for' or something.

```
$.when(
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        $.getScript( "'" + someArr[i].fileName + ".js'");
    }
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ) {
              $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function() {
    alert("done");
});
```

I'm trying to call couple of scripts and then when trey are all loaded I want to an alert to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A commented (but untested) solution with the changes is below

```
// When takes a promise (or list of promises), not a random string of javascript
$.when((function() {
    // First we need to define a self resolving promise to chain to
    var d = $.Deferred().resolve();

    for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

        // Trap the variable i as n by closing it in a function
        (function(n) {

            // Redefine the promise as chaining to itself
            d = d.then(function() {

                // You can *return* a promise inside a then to insert it into
                // the chain. $.getScript (and all ajax methods) return promises
                return $.getScript( someArr[n].fileName + '.js' );
            });

        // Pass in i (becomes n)
        }(i));
    }

    return d;

// self execute our function, which will return d (a promise) to when
}())).then(function() {

    // Note the use of then for this function. done is called even if the script errors.
    console.log( 'done' );
});
```

If you have the option, something much simpler is just

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( 'fileName1.js' ),
    $.getScript( 'fileName2.js' ),
    $.getScript( 'fileName3.js' ),
    $.getScript( 'fileName4.js' )
).then(function() {
    alert("done");
});
```

Comment: and im sorry for the horiifying code..kinda didnt know how to use this function at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the code to do what you want can be written concisely with `$.map()` and `$.when.apply()`, as follows :

```
// First scan someArr, calling $.getScript() and building 
// an array of up to 5 jqXHR promises.
var promises = $.map(someArr, function(obj, index) {
    return (index < 5) ? $.getScript(obj.fileName + ".js") : null;
});
// Now apply the promises to $.when()
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
    alert("done");
});
```

Note: `$.when.apply(null, promises)` is equivalent to :

```
$.when(jqXHR0, jqXHR1, jqXHR2, jqXHR3, jqXHR4);
```

where `jqXHR0` etc. are `jqXHR` objects returned by five `$.getScript()` calls.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine. Would it be safer to do `$.when.apply($` instead of `null`?

Comment: `$.when()` doesn't exploit `this` so you can put what you like in that position, as long as it doesn't generate an error. `null` is as good as anything else.