# Nested AJAX Calls using .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to AJAX, but working on a project that requires an ajax call to validate a specific value, then make another ajax call if the first returns the expected value. I am trying to implement the .done/.fail model, but can't find a way to prevent both calls from happening simultaneously, rather than once the first call is done and successful.

The following code will call the ajaxCall function twice, but concurrently rather than consecutively.  I have researched a ton of code, including [Nested AJAX Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892771/nested-ajax-calls), [jQuery getting rid of nested ajax functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792277/jquery-getting-rid-of-nested-ajax-functions), and [$.when.done callback isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007640/when-done-callback-isnt-working), but none seem to fit my exact scenario, or maybe I just don't understand the code.  Either way, I haven't been able to find a solution, and any help will be much appreciated!

```
var xReturn = ajaxCall("1");    

xReturn.done(function(msg){
    console.log("callback "+msg+" successful");

    // if successful, place second call
    if(parseInt(msg)==1)
        xReturn = ajaxCall("2");    
});


function ajaxCall(mop){
    return $.ajax({
         url: "getItem.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {code: '<?php echo $code; ?> ', op:mop}
    });
}
```

It seems like *promises* may be the way to go, but I can't wrap my head around how to use them in this scenario.  Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction.

Update:

I ran through a battery of tests with different results.  For my final test last night, I placed another `console.log(msg);` directly after `ajaxCall("2");`  Each time the resulting msg was always "1", leading me to believe the calls were not happening properly. This result tells me that `xReturn.done(function(msg)...` is only being called once, but I thought it would be called with each ajax call.

With this new information, I will perform additional testing tonight and report back.
Thanks

Comment: *"It seems like promises may be the way to go, but I can't wrap my head around how to use them in this scenario."* But you are already using promises. `xReturn` is a promise. Anyways, how do you determine that your code runs in parallel? It looks like it should run serially. The callback you pass to `.done` is only executed after the first Ajax finished.

Comment: Why not use `.$.ajax` on both occasions and call the second ajax inside the `success` of first?

Comment: Here is a demo which shows that the Ajax calls are executed in sequence: http://jsfiddle.net/9fT2e/5/.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, I can see ajax calls being executed sequentially. I updated the fiddle a bit, but expected to see the xReturn.done(...) function called a second time as a callback for xReturn=ajaxCall(2);.  How can I identify that the second call was successful?   http://jsfiddle.net/9fT2e/6/

Comment: `xReturn.done` is bound to the 1st `xReturn`.  When you do `xReturn = ajaxCall("2")`, you are setting `xReturn` to a *new* object, so you need to bind `.done()` *again*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a `.done()` method to *each* promise.  `xReturn.done()` binds a function to that promise.

When you do `xReturn = ajaxCall("2");`, you are ***replacing*** `xReturn` with a different object.  This object does not have a `.done()` method bound to it.

You need to bind `.done()` to each promise, that doesn't happen automatically.

```
var xReturn = ajaxCall("1");
// This binds the callback to this *specific* promise    
xReturn.done(ajaxDone);    

function ajaxCall(mop){
    return $.ajax({
         url: "getItem.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {code: '<?php echo $code; ?> ', op:mop}
    });
}

function ajaxDone(msg){
    console.log("callback "+msg+" successful");

    // if successful, place second call
    if(parseInt(msg)==1){
        xReturn = ajaxCall("2");

        // Bind a callback to this *new* object
        xReturn.done(ajaxDone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about this problem.

You could simply call the second ajax call from the success of the first. Something on the following lines

```
function ajaxCall(mop){
    $.ajax({
         url: "getItem.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {code: '<?php echo $code; ?> ', op:mop}
    }).done(function(msg) {
        console.log("First call is done. Received data as ", msg);
        if(parseInt(msg)==1) {
            $.ajax({
                //Repeat Options
            }).done(function(newMsg)) {
                console.log("We're done");
            };
        }
    });
}
```

}

If you do want to use the .done/.fail model, you could try using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).
Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/GZEPQ/) that does consecutive calls using the same function.

```
function ajaxCall(mop){
    return $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                json: $.toJSON({data: mop}),
                delay: Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
            }
    });
}

$.when(ajaxCall("1")).done(function(data) {
    console.log("Done with first call. About to call second");
        if(data /* and add whatever conditions you need to call the next function */) {
            ajaxCall("2");
        }
});
```

Comment: `$.when(ajaxCall("1")).done()` is equivalent to `ajaxCall("1").done()`. If you only pass one argument to `$.when` then  there is no reason to use it. Both of your solutions are identical actually.

Comment: @Felix King: The second one reuses the `ajaxCall` function, which I thought is what the OP required.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
ajaxCall("1"); 

function ajaxCall(mop){
$.post( "getItem.php", {code: '<?php echo $code; ?> ', op:mop})
  .done(function( msg) {
    console.log("callback "+msg+" successful");
    if(parseInt(msg)==1)
        ajaxCall("2"); 
  });

}
```

And also you can use these with previous code

```
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What's wrong with their code?

Comment: Is there nothing wrong why he ask about it???. You are the person who  have edited it

Comment: *"why he ask about it"* That's what I'm trying to find out. I hoped you'd explain since you answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
var xReturn1 = ajaxCall("1"),
    xReturn2 = ajaxCall("2");

$.when(xReturn1, xReturn2).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
    var data1 = a1[0], data2 = a2[0];
    console.log("Both done");
});
```

Comment: Well, this certainly will run the code in parallel and not sequentially (which is what the OP wants, as far as I understood).